# If $K$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, every elements of $K$ is a root of $t^{p^n -1}-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

> **Problem** :
>
> 1. Show that the characteristic of a finite field $K$ is a prime number.
> 2. Show that $K$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and there exists $n$ such that Card($K$) $= p^n$.
> 3. **Show that every non zero elements of $K$ is a root of $t^{p^n -1}-1$.**
> 4. Show that $K$ is the splitting field of $t^{p^n}-t$.

I managed to prove the first and second problems. The first one by contradiction and the second by showing that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ was isomorphic to a subfield of K (the image of the characteristic homomorphism).

However I have difficulties showing the third problem. I think it would equivalent to showing that $\forall x \in K : x^{p^n -1} = 1$, or maybe that $\forall x \in K : x^{p^n} = x$ and use Ferma's little theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there are a couple of slips in your equivalences.  The equation $\ x^{p^n-1} = 1\ $ doesn't hold for *all* $\ x\in K\ $, only for all *non-zero* $\ x\in K\ $, but that's *precisely* what it is that you're being asked to show in the third leg of your problem.  And you can indeed use [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) (a generalisation of Fermat's little theorem) to show it, since the nonzero elements of $\ K\ $ form a multiplicative group of order $\ p^n-1\ $.

The other slip (just a typo, I presume) is in the equation $\ x^{p^n} = p\ $.  This should be $\ x^{p^n} = x\ $.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to figure out how to prove that for any $x \in K$, $x^{p^{n}-1} = 1$, and I totally forgot the group of inversible elements of $K$ was cyclic and precisely of order $p^{n} -1$.

Comment: For the last question, can I conclude that since $t^{p^n}-t=t(t^{p^{n}-1}-1)$ and all the non zero roots of $(t^{p^{n}-1}-1)$ are in $K$ by the 3rd question, and the $0$ root is clearly in $K$, all the roots of $(t^{p^{n}-1}-1)$  are in $K$, thus $K$ is its splitting field?

Comment: You need one more observation.  A splitting field of a polynomial is the  *smallest* extension of the field generated by its coefficients over which the polynomial splits into linear factors.  That's trivially true in this case, because *every* member of $\ K\ $ is a root.